# Why is my string format not working?

Tags: python, string, format

I'm creating a jQuery function on-the-fly with python:

```
jQuery = ("$('%(other_id)').click(function() { "
              "    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { "
              "        $('%(text_id)').show()     "
              "    } "
              "    else {"
              "       $('%(text_id)').hide()"
              "    }"
              " });")
```

I have to insert varibles into `other_id` and `text_id`. I see that `$` sign is used for string templates (don't know what it does though) So I escape them with double-`$`s(`$$`)

```
jQuery = ("$$('%(other_id)').click(function() { "
              "    if ($$(this).is(':checked')) { "
              "        $$('%(text_id)').show()     "
              "    } "
              "    else {"
              "       $$('%(text_id)').hide()"
              "    }"
              " });")
```

However I can't still format this:

```
>>> choice_id = 'foo'
>>> text_choice_id = 'bar'
>>> jQuery = ("$$('%(other_id)').click(function() { "
                  "    if ($$(this).is(':checked')) { "
                  "        $$('%(text_id)').show()     "
                  "    } "
                  "    else {"
                  "       $$('%(text_id)').hide()"
                  "    }"
                  " });")
>>> jQuery %{'other_id' : choice_id, 'text_id' : text_choice_id }

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#123>", line 1, in <module>
    jQuery %{'other_id' : choice_id, 'text_id' : text_choice_id }
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 15
```

after escaping single-quotes:

```
>>> jQuery = ("$$(\'%(other_id)\').click(function() { "
                  "    if ($$(this).is(\':checked\')) { "
                  "        $$(\'%(text_id)\').show()     "
                  "    } "
                  "    else {"
                  "       $$(\'%(text_id)\').hide()"
                  "    }"
                  " });")
>>> jQuery %{'other_id' : choice_id, 'text_id' : text_choice_id }

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#125>", line 1, in <module>
    jQuery %{'other_id' : choice_id, 'text_id' : text_choice_id }
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 15
```

can't try `string.format()` because I have brackets inside the string. why am I keep getting `'` as some unsupported format character?

Comment: You can escape `{` in a format string by doubling: `{{`

Comment: You could use `"""` literals for multiline strings for readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the formatter type:

```
%(other_id)s
```

Note the `s` after the parenthesis; you want to interpolate the values as strings. Here is a working version instead:

```
jQuery = ("$('#%(other_id)s').click(function() { "
                  "    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { "
                  "        $('#%(text_id)s').show()     "
                  "    } "
                  "    else {"
                  "       $('#%(text_id)s').hide()"
                  "    }"
                  " });")
```

Dollar symbols have no meaning in `%`-style string formats and I've added the `#` id selectors for you. :-)

Personally, I would use `"""` triple-quotes instead:

```
jQuery = """\
$('#%{other_id}s').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#%(text_id)s').show()
    }
    else {
        $('#%(text_id)s').hide()
    }
});
"""
```

Better still, put this into a Jinja template anyway (since you are using Flask) and render that instead:

```
jquery = render_template('toggle_field.js', other_id=choice_id, text_id=text_choice_id)
```

where `toggle_field.js` is the Jinja template version of the jQuery snippet:

```
$('#{{ other_id }}').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#{{ text_id }}').show()
    }
    else {
        $('#{{ text_id }}').hide()
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. Also I found that there is no need to escape `$` and I was missing `#` in the selectors.

Comment: @thankg This is a great answer - however, I would probably look at templating libraries also

Comment: @thkang: there you go. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of code generation, consider an approach that is data-driven. Define the following two functions statically, preferably in some js file you include across all your html files:

```
function toggle_if_checked(checkbox, toggleable) {
    var cbox = $(checkbox), tgl = $(toggleable);
    tgl.toggle(cbox.is(':checked'));
}

function register_check_show_events(elist) {
    var i, cboxselector, textselector;
    function handler(e) {
        toggle_if_checked(e.target, e.data);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < elist.length; i++) {
        cboxselector = '#'+elist[0];
        textselector = '#'+elist[1];
        $(cboxselector).on('click', null, textselector, handler);
    }
}
```

Then to register your event handlers, collect a Python list of ids and make it available to javascript via JSON.

```
import json

ids = [('cboxid1','textboxid1'),('cboxid2','textboxid2')]
json_ids = json.dumps(ids)
script = 'register_check_show_events({});'.format(json_ids)
```

In general, your code will be cleaner and easier to maintain if you only pass *data* between your Python and JS layers via JSON rather than generate javascript code dynamically.

Comment: This approach is cleaner and more sane, but since my fields are dynamically generated (from input files) getting all those `id`s will be somewhat problematic. since flask<->wtforms interaction doesn't provide much room for me to intervene, I have to write functions that yields `id`s separately (which has to comply to internal field-name generation rules in wtforms widgets)by going through all the fields, and that is something over my capacity at this moment.. :(

Comment: Even if you can't collect all ids at once, calling `register_check_show_events()` several times (once per id pair as you learn them) would still be easier to read later. Though I understand sometimes code generation is the only way to keep dependencies isolated.